# Eager loading polymorphic relations in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am returning `return $post->comments;` from the controller. But I also need to return the `$post` associated with it. But since `$post->comments` returns multiple instances, I can't even use `->with()` method on it like this:

```
return $post->comments->with('commentable')->get();
// BadMethodCallException: Method with does not exist.
```

This is a polymorphic relation. How do I eagerload the `*-able` related models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the relationship as a method, not as a property:

```php
return $post->comments()->with('commentable')->get();
```

Comment: `->with('comments')->get();` for really calling the relationship